# ACF Display specific field from all posts

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I must display a specific custom field for all articles, I have tried this loop, and I have just partial results (only the newest added articles appear in this loop, the oldest are not).

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $price= get_field (“price”);
    echo the_title().$price.”<br>”;
endwhile;
endif;
```

Any idea how to loop this, to show all articles that have that specific field ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the WP_Query? What have you tried? There are many other posts on this.

Comment: I don't understand, it is not the wp query what I have posted? I'm noob in this area

Answer (score 0):

just add page id or custom post type name in loop

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $price= get_field('price');
    echo the_title()."".$price."<br>";
endwhile;
endif;
```

or  trye below

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $price= get_field('price',get_the_ID());
        echo the_title()."".$price."<br>";
    endwhile;
    endif;
```

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the post title/price ONLY if the price field is set for that post... this might work:

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();       

    // Only show title and price if the price field has a value set
    if(get_field('price', get_the_ID())){

        the_title();
        the_field('price', get_the_ID());
        echo '<br>';

    }

endwhile;
endif;
?>
```